# Make a folder/file Link in 17.04

Tags: directory, 17.04

I just installed 17.04 and I can't figure out how to Make a Link to a file or a folder that I can copy to my desktop. In 16.04 I could right click on a file and select "Make a link."  The Make a Link option is not there in 17.04 so what is the new procedure?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try dragging the file/folder from nautilus to your desktop, but before you release the mouse button to drop the file/folder, press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>. Now release the button. A menu should pop up asking you if you want to move, copy, or link the file to your desktop.

**Exact steps:**

- Navigate to file/folder in nautilus
- Left click and drag, but don't release button
- Press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>
- Release mouse button
- Release <kbd>Alt</kbd>